# ASP.NET MVC is throwing an error while doing aggregation - can anyone help me?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWjQH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtgHW.png)

I have a scoreboard. In this table, when users make a transaction, the score is recorded with that user's id. But someone who is a new member of the site gives the above error because they do not have any data in this table. It can add users with data in the table, but it gives an error when a new user becomes a member. How can I solve this? (I have attached the link of the error image. You can open and see)

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectTiklaKazan.Models.Sınıf;
namespace ProjectTiklaKazan.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AnaMenuController : Controller
    {
        Context c = new Context();
        // GET: AnaMenu
        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Users u = Session["UserID"] as Users;
            var toptohum = c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID).Sum(x => x.PuanMiktar).ToString();
            if (toptohum !=null)
            {
                TempData["toptohum"] = toptohum;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["toptohum"] = 0;
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of PuanMiktar? The error you attached looks like Sum(...) is returning null (probably because there is no data for the user), but doesn't know how to coalesce it to int (which isn't nullable).

Comment: The data type of PuanMiktar is int

Comment: How can I check if it is empty?

Comment: unfortunately, I need more code to be able to help you further. Specifically, the implementation of the type for PuanBilgis, and more specifically the PuanMiktar property. Please update your question to include that, and then I can help further.

It's also unclear where some of your variables are coming from. Where is c initialized or declared?

Comment: ok. I will update now

Comment: I updated the question. I also added the design image of the ScoreInformation table above. Please help me how can I solve it

Comment: The code isn't finding the user.  Try following :  if (toptohum.Count != 0)  Query isn't returning null it is returning an empty object.

Comment: try changing it to this and let me know if it works: c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID).ToList().Sum(x => x.PuanMiktar).ToString()    -- notice that there is a .ToList() in there

Comment: I've tested similar code on my end, and saw the same error. I believe my posted answer addresses your issue. If it does, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: worked. thank you very much. I tried another code like this and it works like this; var toptohum = c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID).Sum(x => (int?)x.PuanMiktar) ?? 0;

Comment: How can I accept your answer? I'm new to the forum, I don't know how to do it?

Comment: click the checkmark under the voting buttons for my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting this issue because `IEnumerable<T>` only knows that a collection has no items in it by iterating over the collection.

In your case, `c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID)` yields an `IEnumerable<>` that has no contents, but it doesn't *know* that it has no contents. Then the `Sum(...)` LINQ extension is called, and tries to iterate over the `IEnumerable<>`, but hits an exception when it tries to read from the database and there is no data to be read.

However, `IList<T>` has a `Count` property on it that keeps track of the number of elements in the collection. So if you can convert your `IEnumerable<T>` into an `IList<T>`, then some of the LINQ extensions will be able to take advantage of the `Count` property and save itself from the cost of enumerating the collection.

This does have an up-front perf cost of enumerating the data entirely instead of on-demand, but it's not much, especially if the collection is empty.

In your case, you could do something like this:

`c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID).ToList().Sum(x => x.PuanMiktar).ToString()`